# How to add multiple attribute and corresponding values within xml child node

Tags: xml, powershell

Add multiple attributes and values to a xml child node.
Ex- I want to add another Rule within Namespace element.

```
<GlobalAppSettings 
  <NameSpace name="retail" 
  </NameSpace>
  <NameSpace name="APEService" inheritsFrom="retail">
    <Rules>
      <Rule namespace="retail" queues="Default" scanInterval="10000" threads="2" />
      <Rule namespace="retail" queues="DLS" scanInterval="9000" threads="1" />
     
    </Rules>
  </NameSpace>
</GlobalAppSettings>
```

I tried adding another element and a text node but am stuck at this point and unable to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the
System.Xml.XmlDocument
to accomplice this

here is an example of how to add an extra rule to your mentioned xml

```
$pathToXml = "C:\temp\xml.xml"

$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load($pathToXml)
$namespaceNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//NameSpace[@name='APEService']")
$rulesNode = $namespaceNode.SelectSingleNode("Rules")

# Adding a new rule:
$ruleNode = $xml.CreateElement("Rule")
$ruleNode.SetAttribute("namespace", "retail")
$ruleNode.SetAttribute("queues", "sometimes")
$ruleNode.SetAttribute("scanInterval", "8000")
$ruleNode.SetAttribute("threads", "2")
$rulesNode.AppendChild($ruleNode)

# Removing a rule:
# Select the rule to be removed by the queues name 
# if you need to remove a complete namespace you could just use @namespace instead of @queues
$ruleToRemove = $rulesNode.SelectSingleNode("Rule[@queues='DLS']")

# Remove the rule from the parent node
$rulesNode.RemoveChild($ruleToRemove)

$xml.Save($pathToXml)
```

Comment: this works just as needed.

Comment: i wanted to also delete one of the rule element within the 'rules' element. whats is the best way to go about this?

Comment: $deletenode = $rulesNode.SelectSingleNode("//rule[@queues='Default']")
$deletenode.GetType(). Running this gives an error - cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Comment: any pointer on how to accomplish this? i want to delete one of the queues

Comment: I have modified my answer to add the code to delete a single rule que and mentioned how you could do it on a namespace instead hope that helps :)

Comment: deviating from the main question, but best way to add a newly created above node at the nth index within the 'Rule' array ?

Comment: Not 100% sure i know what you mean but i am guessing you are looking for a way to sort the rules so they are desending or something along those lines based on either sorting the queues name or maybe the number in the scan interval?
the only way i know of would be to remove all elements from the rules sort them with powershell and then add them again in the correct order

Comment: So, what i need to do is add another Rule - say "Queue= 'NewQueue'". this new queue should be inserted at a certain index within this array, say after "Queue='Default'".

Comment: Okay then to my knowledge the only way to accomplice that would be to remove all elements in the Rules and in powershell sort them as you would like and then append them all at once in the correct order